# Number.toString(2) is omitting 0's from end in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, reverse, tostring, 32-bit

I am trying to reverse the 32-bit unsigned integer by converting it to a string first but the `toString(2)` function is committing the zero's from the end and because of it the output I am getting is wrong.

MyCode:

```
var reverseBits = function(n) {
    let reverserN=(n>>>0).toString(2).split('').reverse().join('');
    console.log(reverserN)
    
    return parseInt(reverserN,2)
};
```

Output:

Your input
`00000010100101000001111010011100`

stdout
`00111001011110000010100101` //0's omitted from the end

Output
`15065253 (00000000111001011110000010100101)`

Expected
`964176192 (00111001011110000010100101000000)`

And, if I try to use `BigInt` then it is giving me `n` at the end. Like this `00111001011110000010100101n`.

Why 0's are omitted? And how can I stop it from omitting 0's from the end?

Comment: Just padEnd with 0's to a length of 32.

Comment: @CharlieAraya `(n>>>0)` is for handling negative numbers. If the input is `-1` then the correct output will be `"11111111111111111111111111111111"`. Otherwise, the output will be `-1` which is incorrect.

Comment: @Liam No, I asked why `toString(2)` is omitting 0's? And, How can I add them back? I didn't ask `how can I reverse an integer?`.

Comment: play some golf? (https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/105633)

Comment: I understand (n>>>0) is for handling negative numbers, but if you input 00011100 the leading zeros will be removed as it handles it as a number and not a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `padEnd(32,0)` after `join('')` works. Which simply added 0's at the end to the resulting string so that it reaches a given length.

Mycode:

```
var reverseBits = function(n) {
    let reverserN=(n>>>0).toString(2).split('').reverse().join('').padEnd(32,0);
    console.log(reverserN);
    return parseInt(reverserN,2)
};
```

Output:

```
00111001011110000010100101000000 //6 0's at the end of the string
```